# Old animated movie about anthropomorphic animals (lion prince in love with enemy girl while engaged to snake princess)

Tags: story-identification, movie, animation

I'm looking for this old animated movie (probably '70's - 2000s, judging by what I remember from the animation).

I don't remember the plot, but the main character was a prince who sort of looked like a lion or feline (still walked on two legs; I think he had a tail and red hair) and fell in love with a girl from the outskirts of his kingdom. I believe her people were related to the water somehow and were considered enemies of the main character's kingdom. I think her people also had blue skin, but I might be wrong.

Another character I remember is a snake princess who was engaged to the main character, and she had a maid. The snake princess was part of a strategic alliance by her father (these two are part of another kingdom) to solidify the relationship between the lion kingdom and the snake kingdom (they were probably not called this), but the lion prince had fallen in love with the enemy girl.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you actually watch this?

Comment: Where did you see this movie? In what country, and what format?  Vhs, tv channel,  dvd, or theatre?

Comment: My immediate reaction was that this sounds like Disney's [Robin Hood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robin_Hood_(1973_film)), but on closer inspection, some of the details don't seem to match.

Comment: @LogicDictates I was very young so it must have been 2006-2010

Comment: @myriaidee1sessh43 I watched it in Cuba, in the TV. There is a high chance it might be a European movie because most of the ones I remembered and I've found from my childhood were obscure films from France (like Carnivale and Les Enfants de la pluie). I can't say for certain it is as I watched it in Spanish.

Comment: @eowirh what I sometimes I think of the channel and try to search for the schedule of the time. Maybe even google movies that have been shown on this channel. I also google like lists of movies of a certain country or something similar, and wiki is a good place to do. This link is to wiki and seems to have a good list of all or most animated movies by decades and years. Sometimes I go there and go by the names and search the ones that might be familiar to the title or reminds me of the plot. You can try giving it a try. 
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_animated_feature_films

Comment: Aside from the fact that the people were animals, was there anything about this film that was sci-fi or fantasy?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think it might be an Italian animated film from 2001, ***[Aida of the Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aida_of_the_Trees)***, AKA *Aida degli alberi*.

It is based on the opera "Aida" by Giuseppe Verdi (1813-1901), adapted to young audiences with an environmentalist message.

> Arborea and Petra are two neighbouring countries perpetually at war with one another. Only the romantic relationship between Aida, the daughter of the Arborean king, and Radames, the brave son of the high general of Petra, will change the situation. The couple's worst enemy is Ramfis, the high priest of the evil god Satam, who would like his clumsy son Kak to marry the princess of Petra (who's engaged to Radames). After a series of adventures and fierce battles, Aida and Radames will manage to defeat Ramfis, to end the war between their countries and to live happily ever after.

The hero, Radames, is indeed an anthropomorphic lion with red hair and a tail, and he is in love with the blue-skinned enemy princess, Aida:

[image: Main characters Aida and Radames]

The "princess of Petra," who is engaged to Radames, is Amneris, pictured as an anthropomorphic snake:

[image: Snake princess Amneris]

YouTube has the full movie in the original Italian:

Comment: It appears the snake princess is mentioned in the Wikipedia synopsis quoted in your answer, though by title rather than by name: _"**the princess of Petra** (who's engaged to Radames)"_. Radames is apparently the son of a general, rather than a prince, but aside from that, this seems to match the description given in the question very closely.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right! I missed that. I edited it my the answer. Thank you

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much. This is the movie!!!

Comment: From the question, it was clear someone had adapted _[Aïda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aida)_.

Answer (score 8):

[*Argai: The Prophecy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argai:_The_Prophecy)

Not quite sure if it is this series. I tried looking for an episode summary, but not much of a success.

Characters from the series resemble the description of the question.

The summary is very different but it might be an episode you may had seen instead, and you may have believed it was a movie:

> New York 2075. The evil Queen Dark rules the world and by casting a spell upon girls she remains alive forever. Prince Argai from 1250 a.d. is furious when he discovers his fiancee Angel has been enchanted; a lightning flash sends him to 2075 where he seeks refuge with private detective Oscar Lightbulb, his assistant Barnaby and their secretary Miss Moon. It is discovered that a book of prophecies exists that details every ingredient they need for the potion to rescue Angel. They copy this book, but it gets stolen by Queen Dark who then knows their every next move. Will they succeed in collecting the ingredients, rescuing Angel and the destruction of Queen Dark?!

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I had already considered this but I disregarded it as I distinctly remembered the snake princess was not the main villain, but her father. She had a redemption arc towards the end of the movie where she accepted the prince was in love with the other girl. Another thing that led me to disregard this option is because I remember the scene where the lion prince and the girl first met and she took him to her people who lived hiding in the forest, in this series they already start as a couple. The characters are similar that what I remember (except the girl, whom I cannot remember)